# In python is there a better way of adding fields to a structured numpy array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, structured-array

```
new_dtyp = ny.dtype(finpat.dtype.descr + [('sl','i8'),('diff','i8'),('errtot','i8')])
paterror = ny.array(finpat, dtype=new_dtyp)
```

The code used by me though works but gives warning message. Given below...

FutureWarning: Assignment between structured arrays with different field names will change in numpy 1.14.

Previously fields in the dst would be set to the value of the identically-named field in the src. In numpy 1.14 fields will instead be assigned 'by position': The Nth field of the dst will be set to the Nth field of the src array.

See the release notes for details

What do I do so that the warning message is taken care. Not silencing it.

Comment: Functions in `numpy.lib.recfunctions` creates a new 'empty' array, and copies fields by name.

Answer (score 1):

The warning has nothing to do with the way you're setting the dtype, it's just there to indicate that starting in numpy 1.14, the way the object `finpat` is converted to your custom structured array may be different than expected. This applies if the field names of the values in finpat match or are in a different order than specified in the `new_dtyp` you have defined.

You can find more information in the numpy 1.14 release notes (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/release.html#multiple-field-indexing-assignment-of-structured-arrays).

> The indexing and assignment of structured arrays with multiple fields
>   has changed in a number of ways, as warned about in previous releases.
>
> First, indexing a structured array with multiple fields, e.g.,
>   `arr[['f1', 'f3']]`, returns a view into the original array instead of
>   a copy. The returned view will have extra padding bytes corresponding
>   to intervening fields in the original array, unlike the copy in 1.13,
>   which will affect code such as `arr[['f1', 'f3']].view(newdtype)`.
>
> Second, assignment between structured arrays will now occur “by
>   position” instead of “by field name”. The Nth field of the destination
>   will be set to the Nth field of the source regardless of field name,
>   unlike in numpy versions 1.6 to 1.13 in which fields in the
>   destination array were set to the identically-named field in the
>   source array or to 0 if the source did not have a field.
>
> Correspondingly, the order of fields in a structured dtypes now
>   matters when computing dtype equality. For example, with the dtypes
>
> ```
> x = dtype({'names': ['A', 'B'], 'formats': ['i4', 'f4'], 'offsets': [0, 4]})
> y = dtype({'names': ['B', 'A'], 'formats': ['f4', 'i4'], 'offsets': [4, 0]})
> ```
>
> the expression `x == y` will now return `False`, unlike before. This
>   makes dictionary based dtype specifications like `dtype({'a': ('i4',
>   0), 'b': ('f4', 4)})` dangerous in python < 3.6 since dict key order
>   is not preserved in those versions.
>
> Assignment from a structured array to a boolean array now raises a
>   ValueError, unlike in 1.13, where it always set the destination
>   elements to `True`.
>
> Assignment from structured array with more than one field to a
>   non-structured array now raises a ValueError. In 1.13 this copied just
>   the first field of the source to the destination.
>
> Using field “titles” in multiple-field indexing is now disallowed, as
>   is repeating a field name in a multiple-field index.
>
> The documentation for structured arrays in the user guide has been
>   significantly updated to reflect these changes.

Answer (score 0):

The general strategy in `numpy.lib.recfunctions` is to copy data by field name from the original to new structure.

As a simple example:

```
In [186]: x = np.array([('one',1),('two',2)], dtype='U3,int')
In [187]: x
Out[187]: array([('one', 1), ('two', 2)], dtype=[('f0', '<U3'), ('f1', '<i4')])
In [188]: y = np.empty(2, dtype=x.dtype.descr+[('three',float)])
In [189]: y
Out[189]: 
array([('', 0, 0.), ('', 0, 0.)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<U3'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('three', '<f8')])
In [190]: for n in x.dtype.names:
     ...:     y[n] = x[n]
     ...:     
In [191]: y
Out[191]: 
array([('one', 1, 0.), ('two', 2, 0.)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<U3'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('three', '<f8')])
```

In 1.14 I get error with you kind of assignment.

```
In [192]: z = np.array(x, dtype=y.dtype)
ValueError: structures must have the same size
```

I don't recall ever trying this in earlier versions.